# How to update a data by using Dictionary efficiently?

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
private readonly Dictionary<Credentials, Data> _dataToCredentialMap = 
             new Dictionary<Credentials, Data>();
```

`Credentials` contains `SqlCredentials` and `ExchangeCredentials` properties.
`Data` have `SqlData` and `ExchangeData` and other properties.

I use the following method to update `_dataToCredentialMap` each minute

```
private void UpdateData()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var credential in _dataToCredentialMap.Keys)
        {
            var data = GetData(credential);
            _dataToCredentialMap[credential] = data;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          _logger.WarnException(ex, "Failed to update agent metadata");
     }
}
```

But when I go through the `_dataToCredentialMap.Keys` I can have the following request situation:

first element in the dictionary contains `credential1, sqlcredential2` inside key and some `Data` value, the second one can contains `sqlcredential2, credential3` key and some `Data` value. So when I call `GetData(credential)` inside loop I call it with the same `sqlcredential2` twice and collect the same `Data.SqlData`. I don't want to do that.

I think about adding two additional dictionary's

```
private readonly Dictionary<SqlCredentials, SqlData> _sqlDictionary;
private readonly Dictionary<ExchangeCredentials, ExchangeData> _exchangeDictionary;
```

and update it inside loop, because I have `GetSqlData(credential)` and `GetExchengeData(credential)` inside `GetData()`. But I dont now how to combine the result.

Comment: I don't understand "first element in the dictionary contains <SqlDatabase1, ExchangeDatabase2> key-credentials, the second one contains <ExchangeDatabase2, SqlDatabase3> key-credentials and when I call GetData(credential) I do the same work to update data for ExchangeDatabase2 credential twice." can you explain or how `GetData`?

Comment: Just keep a `List` where you put the queried databases and only get the data if it's not already in that list.

Comment: @Joe My dictionary can contains collections of credentials - its a keys, this keys are different. But collections can have equals elements. And when I update dictionary I call `GetData(credential)` and I can collect same data, beacuse the same credential, I don't want to do that

Comment: You can add two dict with <sqlCred, sqlData>, <exchCred, exchData> and update it inside loop

Answer (score -3):

I believe what's happening here is that, since you are modifying the dictionary as you are going through it, its causing an error. If you fix that, you shouldn't need the try/catch statement, then it should work as expected.

You can create a new `dictionary` called `tempDict`, like so:

```
var tempDict;
copyDictionary(_dataToCredentialMap, tempDict);
foreach(var crediental in tempDict)
{
    var data = GetData(crediental);
    _dataToCredentialMap[crediental] = data;
}
```

Not sure if this is what you meant, the exact problem is unclear.

**Edit:** Added the copying of the old dictionary into the temporary one.

Comment: `tempDict` is a reference to the same underlying dictionary.  You haven't really changed anything here.

Comment: Sorry, its not what I mean. I dont want to call GetData with the same credential (Sql or Exchenge) each time in the loop

Comment: @James, you're right, forgot C# was pass by reference. I just fixed that now.

I'm mildly confused, because you keep talking about <T1, T2> then, later <T2, T1>, but basically you want to make sure you don't call the same function with the same argument to get the same result?

If that's the case, I think the overhead required to check for that case would be more than the current overhead.

Comment: You code have the same problem. @ipetr don't want to call `GetData` with the same credential

Comment: @Anatoly, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to say, you're English is well written. Are you saying my code has the same problem because ipetr doesn't want to call 'GetData' with the same credential? If that's the case, I know that I didn't fix that part. I already said that calling it twice for the same credential isn't that big of a deal performance wise to call for any method of checking during each iteration to see if its already been used before.